# How can I send an ajax request to controller backend php file from tpl file in CS cart?

Tags: php, ajax, smarty, cs-cart

Below is the code, I am new in cs cart and unable to figure out how can I get the ajax call from tpl in php file.
I want to implement a file upload feature into the admin panel of cs cart.
hooks/order_management/upload_data.tpl
`

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert("doc ready");
            $("#btn_ok").click(function( event ) {
               event.preventDefault();
                var val = $("#myfile").val();
                var data = "data=" + val;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '../../../app/addons/ugw_upload_form/controllers/backend/order_management.post.php',
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,                    

                    success: function(response)
                     { console.log(response);}
               });
             });
        });
        </script>

        <div class="control-group">
         <input type="text" name="myfile" id="myfile" />
         <input type="button" id="btn_ok" name="submit" value="upload" >
        </div>`
```

controller/backend/order_management.post.php
`

```
        if (!defined('BOOTSTRAP')) { die('Access denied'); }
        use Tygh\Registry;

        Registry::get('view')->assign('test_var', "Test");
        Registry::get('view')->assign('uploadhere', "upload the file here");


           if(isset($_POST['data'])){
               $textvalue = $_POST['data'];    
                $handle = fopen("Z:\members.txt", "w");
                fwrite($handle, $textvalue);
                fclose($handle);
           }
        ?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the redirection of url in case of ajax request is the fn_get_route() method in app\function\fn.control.php

```
function fn_get_route(&$req, $area = AREA){
:::
Registry::set('runtime.controller', !empty($parts[0]) ? basename($parts[0]) : 'index');
Registry::set('runtime.mode', !empty($parts[1]) ? basename($parts[1]) : 'index');
::
}
```

fn.commom.php

```
function fn_redirect(){
::
if (defined('AJAX_REQUEST')) { 
// make in-script redirect during ajax request
$_purl = parse_url($location);
$_GET = array();
$_POST = array();
if (!empty($_purl['query'])) {
parse_str($_purl['query'], $_GET);}
$_REQUEST = Bootstrap::safeInput($_GET);
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_purl['path'];
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = !empty($_purl['query']) ? $_purl['query'] : '';
fn_get_route($_REQUEST);
::
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For ajax request in cs-cart you can see: http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.3.x/core/front-end/ajax.html

for example you want to send data over ajax:

---

## Your `demo.tpl` file:

```
<form class="cm-ajax" method="post">
    <input id="elm_id" type="submit" name="dispatch[your_controller.your_mode]" value="submit" />
</form>
```

---

## `your_controller.php`:

```
if($mode == your_mode){
    if (defined('AJAX_REQUEST')) {
        // your operation
        // return or exit;
    }
}
```

---